# Unable to access Physical file (mp3) in Maui app (.net 7)

Tags: maui, mp3, filenotfoundexception, local-files

I have a .net maui app, (.Net 7) which downloads mp3 files, to "/data/user/0/com.companyname.myapp/files/Download"

I have tried to play them back using a webview:

```
<audio controls>
            <source src="/data/user/0/com.companyname.myApp/files/Download/2012-05-06_AM1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
            Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio controls>
```

Which does not work, as the play arrow is just Greyed out.

also tried prefixing file with : src="file///data/user/0/ ....

That does not work either.

If I try

```
if (File.Exists("/data/user/0/com.companyname.myApp/files/Download/2012-05-06_AM1.mp3" ))
{
    Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Found", "File Exists", "OK");
}
```

The file is found,

I have also tried using the following function, and passing the file ref in the mp3 parameter:

```
private async  void MyPlayer(string mp3) {
    var audioPlayer = AudioManager.Current.CreatePlayer(await     FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync(mp3));
    audioPlayer.Play();
}
```

This also errors with file not found.

Any Ideas would be appreciated. This is very frustrating.

If I use a https url, it all works fine. Just when using a local file. I want the app to be able to play downloaded files, when offline,

Comment: Consider downloading the mp3 file in [FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/file-system-helpers?view=net-maui-7.0&tabs=android#app-data-directory) folder and then use `FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync(mp3)` to play it.

Comment: Thank you Alexander. Merry Christmas.  Unfortunately I tried using  FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory to download the mp3, but  I still have the same problem,.   File.Exists("/data/user/0/com.companyname.myapp/files/Download/2015-06-28_AM.mp3");

returns true,, but  FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync("/data/user/0/com.companyname.myapp/files/Download/2015-06-28_AM.mp3")
 
Returns file not found exception..

Comment: Merry Christmas too! Are you downloading the file in the android emulator or the real device? If so, can you try to save the file in the external storage? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/73469775

Comment: Hi There. I have tried on both emulator and physical device.  Both return  
    System.IO.FileNotFoundException: '/data/user/0/com.companyname.myapp/files/Downloads/sermon.mp3'  but:  File.Exists(FileUri) (where FileUri is the path to mp3) returns true.  I have tried using Plugin.Maui.Audio;,  and  var player = AudioManager.Current.CreatePlayer(await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync(filePath));
player.Play();   this fgives same file not found exception.

Comment: also used:   string downloadsFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);  to get dir. Which resolved to  /data/user/0/com.companyname.myapp/files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now resolved. I used  CommunityToolkit.Maui.MediaElement Mediaplayer
MyMediaPlayer.Source = MediaSource.FromFile(""/data/user/0/com.companyname.myApp/files/Download/2012-05-06_AM1.mp3");

```
And this works perfectly.
```